# Tinye MCE and Django: HTMLField toolbar options (admin)

Tags: python, django, tinymce

I have a Djando App running, I added a new simple Model with an order and a content field, the content is of type HTMLField, I manage to edit the field's content and format it just fine, my problem is that I need to be able to add bulleted lists in that field and I cannot find the way to tweak Tiny MCE's configuration to make it happen.

I have tried to add tiny_mce.js file along with another js file with the parameters, and add a TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG section to config.py, but it's not working at all, I'm BTW new to Django and Python

I'd appreciate if someone could give me a guide to be able to handle the Tiny MCE toolbar options from zero

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone may be facing a similar issue I finally came with this solution:

In the settings.py (in my case a partial base.py file) you have to add this lines:

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
'plugins': ["lists"],
'toolbar': ['numlist bullist'],
'theme': "silver"
```

}

Observe that theme is 'silver' and not 'advanced' or 'simple' as some other posts suggest, when I was setting theme as such values the field disappeared from the admin, also, you have to activate the lists plugin and the also add the toolbar items in order to see the buttons.

Hope this can help!